# Why Does Reducing Cardinality of Keyspace Improves Throughput/Performance for Streaming Aggregation for Cloud Dataflow

Tags: streaming, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

When writing an Apache Beam/Dataflow job, reducing cardinality of keyspace significantly improves the performance of grouping functions more than reducing the payload size. Does this have to do with shuffling cost, this means transferring more bytes for a single key has smaller cost than having to move around more keys? Any publications or documentation that explains the reasoning would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Maybe this video can help you, https://youtu.be/Wy6pybh5G4A?t=13189 as it's also touching this topic, the keyspace and the impact on parallelism.

Comment: Can you provide some code snippets illustrating in more detail the situations you're comparing? And if possible, also include some metrics from the Dataflow console or other details describing the differing results that you see? Dataflow performance is a very complex thing affected by many factors, so this needs more detail to be able to point out any specific reasons for the difference you're seeing.